# bash how to create a menu with submenu

Tags: command-line, bash

I need help. Im new at bash shell programming, I have task to do. 
So, I need to make menu and in menu a submenu. 
I mean, then u press 5 (database management) it has to show submenu with 3 options. I tried some methods with if but I cant get it done.
This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3='Please enter your option: '
options=("Buy" "Sale" "Change data" "View cars" "Database management" "Calculate profits" "Sold cars" "Vechiles in stock" "Exit program")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
    "Buy")
        echo "you chose choice 1"
        ;;
    "Sale")
        ;;
    "Change data")
        ;;
    "View cars")
        ;;
    "Database management")
    PS3='Please enter your option: '
    options=("1" "2" "3")
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
    case $opt in
    "1")
        echo "you chose choice 1"
        ;;
    "2")
        echo "you chose choice 2"
    "3")
        echo "you chose choice 3"
        ;;
    "Calculate profits")
        ;;
    "Sold cars")
        ;;
    "Vechiles in stock")
        ;;
    "Exit program")
        break 
        ;;
    *)
        echo "invalid option $REPLY"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

If press 5, it has to pop out another menu with "Back up" "Delete" "Restore" 
Thank you.

Comment: so why don't you copy the whole thing over, add it to option 5 and change the text?

Comment: Okey I will try it

Comment: But I get unexpected end of file. How should I end script under option 5?

Comment: Syntax error, most likely. You should post the updated code…

Comment: Updated. I did like he said.

Comment: You have to close `do ` with `done`. One of your `do`'s is missing `done`.

Comment: There are 2 cases but only 1 esac.

Comment: Another question, is it possible to read from another file? Like for example, I have to files first.sh and second.sh. In first.sh i have all information about cars and in second.sh i have menu. So can I read info I need from first.sh by pressing menu from second.sh? I know you can call out bash first.sh and nano first.sh but i need to read one line from first.sh not all file. I hope u understand

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a shell function for the submenu - as well as making the code more manageable, it allows you to define a `local PS3` to make it easier for the user to keep track of which menu they're in. A minimal prototype might be something like

```
# submenu
submenu () {
  local PS3='Please enter sub option: '
  local options=("Sub menu item 1" "Sub menu item 2" "Sub menu quit")
  local opt
  select opt in "${options[@]}"
  do
      case $opt in
          "Sub menu item 1")
              echo "you chose sub item 1"
              ;;
          "Sub menu item 2")
              echo "you chose sub item 2"
              ;;
          "Sub menu quit")
              return
              ;;
          *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
      esac
  done
}

# main menu
PS3='Please enter main option: '
options=("Main menu item 1" "Submenu" "Main menu quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Main menu item 1")
            echo "you chose main item 1"
            ;;
        "Submenu")
            submenu
            ;;
        "Main menu quit")
            exit
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```

Of course, you could define the main menu in a shell function as well if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks dude, I will try your way

Answer (score 2):

Late addition  I know - you may be able to use this menu program that I'm working on:https://github.com/steveh250/Unix-Menu-Program/tree/1.11

Latest version: https://github.com/steveh250/Unix-Menu-Program

Comment: That's interesting! Please add the basic steps of how to install and use your program. As it currently is your answer might be removed as being link-only. Please see [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Million thanks for this!!

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog - The updated page has instructions on how to build and use the menu.  Thanks.

Comment: @SriramKannan - I have updated the code since then and added the ability to use the simple character menu or a character graphic menu: https://github.com/steveh250/Unix-Menu-Program